# Settings the webroot path via appsettings.json in the new minimal hosting model

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-minimal-apis

In the new ASP.NET Core 6 minimal hosting model, how do I set the webroot from the usual `appsettings.{Environment}.json` files (*and all the other usual configuration sources the hosting builder sets up by default*)?

When I do it via `builder.WebHost.UseWebRoot` like in the below example I will get an exception.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// setup a default value in case it's not set in appsettings.{Environment}.json
builder.Configuration.AddInMemoryCollection(
    new Dictionary<string, string?>
    {
        ["webroot"] = "website",
    });

// NotSupportedException:
builder.WebHost
    .UseWebRoot(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("webroot")!);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.Run();
```

This is the exception I get:

> System.NotSupportedException: The web root changed from "C:\source\MyServer\bin\Debug\net8.0" to "C:\source\MyServer\website". Changing the host configuration using WebApplicationBuilder.WebHost is not supported. Use WebApplication.CreateBuilder(WebApplicationOptions) instead.

But when I change as way suggested in the exception text, I cannot use the pre-built `builder.Configuration` as the source because the `builder` is not yet available.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    WebRootPath = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("webroot") // does not compile
});

// setup a default value in case it's not set in appsettings.{Environment}.json
builder.Configuration.AddInMemoryCollection(
    new Dictionary<string, string?>
    {
        ["webroot"] = "website"
    });

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.Run();
```

How can I use the default `appsettings.{Environment}.jon` (*and all the other usual configuration sources the `builder` sets up by default*) as the source for the webroot path.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a configuration like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    WebRootPath = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args).Configuration.GetValue<string>("webroot") != null ? WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args).Configuration.GetValue<string>("webroot") : "website"
});
Console.WriteLine($"WebRootPath: {builder.Environment.WebRootPath}");
```

Test Result:

[image]